# How to ignore whitespace in detecting author for SVN in netbeans?

Tags: svn, version-control, netbeans

Netbeans has nice option of showing the author of specific line by using
`team`->`show annotations`

However, if somebody just reformats that specific line, s/he is declared as author.

I can ignore those changes when doing diff by ignoring whitespace, can something similar be done so netbeans ignores whitespace changes as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the Subversion annotations and who it claims is the author of any given line, I do not believe that you can change that.  Subversion tracks those changes, and NetBeans is just reporting what SVN tells it.

To have NB ignore whitespace changes in diffs, open up your NB Preferences, select "Miscellaneous" along the top, go to the "Diff" tab, and there are multiple ways to ignore whitespace there.

- Ignore Leading And Trailing White Space
- Ignore Changes In Inner Whitespace
- Ignore Changes In Case