# Ignore whitespaces in Netbeans merging with svn

Tags: svn, netbeans

Netbeans integration of svn shows all differences that have been made to the local files and suggests them for a commit, if changed. The Problem is however, that differences in whitespaces will tag files as changed, as well. Therefore a lot of unnecessary merging has to be done. I know you can edit the behaivour of treating whitespaces under Under Option > Miscellaneous > Diff, but that has no effect on the merging.

Is there any way to auto merge those differences in whitespaces just like the

> svn diff -x -w

command?

I have already found some posts, adressing the same issue, however without providing a satisfing solution: 
[First Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097063/how-to-ignore-whitespace-in-detecting-author-for-svn-in-netbeans), 
[Second Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478145/how-can-i-ignore-whitespace-in-the-netbeans-merge-tool)

Cheers